# Excel VBA Run-time error 91, when copying macro to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is causing a

> run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

This code works fine in the Excel Workbook in which I created it, but when I copy and paste it to another Excel Workbook I get the error.

Error is at line

```
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
```

Does anybody know why?

I have tried to set the variable to a value after it is declared, but this does not solve.

```
 Sub mileStoneDatePivot()


 Dim r As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long, v() As Long, i As Long
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim lCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "DataSheet"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Switch off error masking
On Error GoTo 0



 'This sheet is where data should originate


   Sheets("DCC_AGGREGATOR_FLATFILE").Rows("1").Copy Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A1")

LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: Sorry it is at line `LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _ `

Comment: Is the sheet blank when the code runs?

Answer (score 2):

`Find` returns `Nothing` when it can't find what you've requested.
When you ask it to find `*` (anything) on a blank sheet it returns nothing - it couldn't find anything.
When you ask it to return the row number of nothing it gives the error message you're getting.

To avoid this error pass the result of `Find` to a range variable:

```
Dim rLastRow as Range    
Set rLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False)
```

You can then check if the range is nothing before getting the row number:

```
If Not rLastRow Is Nothing Then
    LastRow = rLastRow.Row
End If
```

I'd suggest looking at one of the posts on finding the last cell and pulling the whole thing out to a separate function.
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=find+last+cell+vba

**Edit:**  Also, your `Find` is only looking at the activesheet.
`LastRow = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Datasheet").Cells.Find....` will always look at the *Datasheet* in the workbook holding the code.